# How to transform an array with map instead of forEach fulfilling the missing sequence with zeros?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-6

I would like to transform an array or object fulfilling with zeros the missing values sequentially. 
For instance from `Input: {Id0:9, Id1:1, Id3:1, Id5:6}` to `Outputs: [9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6]`

I have solved the problem with the following piece of code using `forEach` but would like to know if there is a nicer solution with the function `map`.

```
var tasks = [
  { "_id": 0, "count": 9 },
  { "_id": 1, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": 3, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": 5, "count": 6 }
]
var task_ids = [];
tasks.forEach(function (task) {
  if (task._id == task_ids.length) {
    task_ids.push(task.count);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, max = (task._id-task_ids.length); i < max; i += 1) {
        task_ids.push(0);
    }
    task_ids.push(task.count);
  }
});

// Outputs: [9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6]
console.log(task_ids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think forEach is the cleanest approach here, I would just simplify a little bit your code as below:

```
var tasks = [
    { "_id": 0, "count": 9 },
    { "_id": 1, "count": 1 },
    { "_id": 5, "count": 6 }
];

var task_names = [];
tasks.forEach(task => {
    while (task._id !== task_names.length) {
        task_names.push(0);
    }
    task_names.push(task.count);
});
console.log(task_names); // [9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6]
```

Comment: This solution is working with the initial sample provided but not with multiple missing sequences, like for

    `var tasks = [
      { "_id": 0, "count": 9 },
      { "_id": 1, "count": 1 },
      { "_id": 5, "count": 6 }
    ];`

then the solution is `[9, 1, 0, 6]` instead of `[9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6]`

Comment: @PiiXiieeS: I see: in that case you need to replace the if statement with a while. I amended my answer. This covers both scenarios you described.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (reasonably) use `map` for that. `map` produces a new array with the same number of entries as the original array. `forEach` is the correct solution here. (Some might use `reduce`, continually passing around the array as the "accumulator," but it's much of a muchness and sometimes considered an "abusage" of `reduce` [since the value of the accumulator never changes, just its state].)

Answer (score -1):

The [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) + [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) + [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) version:

```
var tasks = [
  { "_id": 0, "count": 9 },
  { "_id": 1, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": 3, "count": 1 },
  { "_id": 5, "count": 6 }
]

var task_ids = tasks.reduce((acc, t) => {
  if(t._id !== acc.length) {
    Array.from(Array(t._id - acc.length)).forEach(j => acc.push(0));
  }
  acc.push(t.count);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(task_ids); // [9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6]
```

And the vervion with `while` loop inside:

```
var task_ids = tasks.reduce((acc, task) => {
  while(task._id !== acc.length) {
    acc.push(0);
  }
  acc.push(task.count);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(task_ids); // [9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6]
```

The main advantage of the reduce-approach is the declaring of `task_ids` array isn't separated from its populating.

Answer (score -1):

You may do as follows;

```js
var obj    = {Id0:9, Id1:1, Id3:1, Id5:6},
    sparse = Object.keys(obj).reduce((s,k) => (s[+k.replace(/[^\d]+/,"")] = obj[k],s), []);
    dense  = Object.assign(Array(sparse.length).fill(0),sparse);
console.log(dense);
```